# Flatten and rename multi-index agg columns

Tags: pandas

I have some Pandas / [cudf](https://rapidsai.github.io/projects/cudf/en/latest/#) code that aggregates a particular column using two aggregate methods, and then renames the multi-index columns to flattened columns.

```
df = (
    some_df
    .groupby(["some_dimension"])
    .agg({"some_metric" : ["sum", "max"]})
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"some_dimension" : "some_dimension__id", ("some_metric", "sum") : "some_metric_sum", ("some_metric", "max") : "some_metric_max"})
)
```

This works great in cudf, but does not work in Pandas 0.25 -- the hierarchy is not flattened out.

Is there a similar approach using Pandas?  I like the cudf tuple syntax and how they just implicitly flatten the columns.  Hoping to find a similarly easy way to do it in Pandas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas 0.25.0+ there is something called [groupby aggregation with relabeling](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling).

Here is a stab at your code

```
df = (some_df
      .groupby(["some_dimension"])
      .agg(some_metric_sum=("some_metric", "sum"),
           some_metric_max=("some_metric", "max"]})
      .reset_index()
      .rename(colunms = {"some_dimension":"some_dimension_id"}))
```

Comment: if you rest_index first it will try to set the same column name as existing and throwing the error before try of renaming